# OWIN Cookie Auth Not Returning Cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm creating an application using OWIN without using ASP Identity. I've struggled to find any documentation on this as 99% of material out there is using Identity with OWIN.

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        //
        // Wires up WebApi to Owin pipeline
        //
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        app.UseWebApi(config);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {

            CookieDomain = ".devdomain.com",
            CookieName = "AuthCookie",

        });

    }

}
```

**API Controller**

```
    public void Login(string id)
    {

        var authentication = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("Application");

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "<user name>"));

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("CompanyId", id));

        authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(identity, new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            IsPersistent = true
        });


    }
```

When I invoke the Login method it creates a new identity signs the user in. However a cookie isn't returned in the response.

Am I missing something?